# Символ "ножницы" из Unicde

Tags: javascript

Для вывода символа "ножницы" из Unicode запрашиваю их по коду вот так:

```
alert(String.fromCharCode(&#x2702));
```

Однако алерта нет. Оборачивал код в кавычки, всё равно нет. Подскажите где ошибся?

Comment: JS это не HTML. посмотрите как записываются числа в javascript (как в прочем и большинстве других ЯП). `alert(String.fromCharCode(0x2702));` отлично работает ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) принимает в качестве аргумента **число**. Вы же пытаетесь передать ему невалидную (с точки зрения JS) конструкцию. Заключение этой конструкции в кавычки так же не поможет, поскольку, повторюсь, вам нужно **число**.

Вот пример того, как передать шестнадцатиричное число в качестве аргумента:

```
alert(String.fromCharCode(0x2702));
```

[Рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/w6p33647/) на JSFiddle.